# capturePicture() to bitmap results into out of memory

Tags: java, android, exception

I'm new to Android/Java programming and trying to get a bitmap from webview.capturePicture().  However, in cases where the web page is long, the Picture's height is too big and createBitmap() is returning out of memory. My questions are:

1. Is there a way to extract the Picture in sub so createBitmap() does not need a lot of memory?
2. Is there another way to get the web view image other than capturePicture()?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

```
View view = getWindow().getDecorView();
Display display = this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
view.layout(0, 0, display.getWidth(), display.getHeight());
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());
```

in this way you can get a Bitmap.